# Mysql delete select

Tags: mysql, select, delete-row

```
DELETE FROM `lif_1`.`geo_patch` WHERE `TerID` IN ( SELECT * FROM (SELECT `TerID` FROM `lif_1`.`geo_patch` WHERE `LevelFlags` = '22' ) AS p);
```

Seems like it's not woeking, what am I doing wrong?

I would like to find all that have `LevelFlags=22`, so I can find their `TerID` and delete them.

Comment: Is `LevelFlags` CHAR or numeric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use a self join

```
DELETE t.*
FROM geo_patch t
JOIN geo_patch t1 ON(t.TerID = t1.TerID)
WHERE t1.LevelFlags = '22'
```

Comment: SELECT t.*
FROM geo_patch t
JOIN geo_patch t1 ON(t.TerID = t1.TerID)
WHERE t1.LevelFlags = '22';

With this, I should be able to see if the delete works right?